# How does gravity affect density?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, density

In massive objects, gas can be compressed, raising the density of the celestial body. Does this mean that if I create 100 stars and planets, all with the same density and random sizes, some of those stars are unlikely to exist?

Answer (score 3):

The size of a body such as a star or planet is set by the competing forces of gravity and pressure. Gravity tends to cause contraction, while pressure can exert an outward force which halts collapse. The source of the pressure can be hydrostatic (e.g. ordinary star, gas giant) or more exotic, such as electron or neutron degeneracy pressure (white dwarf or neutron star, respectively). The relationship between mass and size is not straightforward, because the density, temperature and pressure all vary with the radius. In some conditions this can trigger nuclear fusion, which usually injects a lot of thermal energy into the gas. Which elements fuse and at what rates depends on the thermodynamic environment in a complicated way.

So your 100 random stars and planets of fixed density will not be stable; some will have stronger gravity than pressure and shrink, others will have stronger pressure than gravity and expand. Eventually I would expect all of them to find their equilibrium state and *become* "realistic", or if the density is high enough, collapse into black holes.

Comment: I see, is there a way to calculate what the equilibrium state would be?

Comment: @Bodhi1 Of course. How to do it, and how difficult it will be, depends on the type of object (for starters).

Comment: What if we assume it's a homogeneous sphere of 1 element for example like hydrogen? What are the factors at play here and what information do we need to know to calculate the equilibrium state?

Comment: For example, a sphere of gas with a starting radius 10e8m, and a mass of 10e20kg made up of hydrogen?

Comment: That's a pretty easy case since that's well shy of the mass needed to get H fusion going. Not going to work the math for you on this: other than the exact numbers you're requesting, this is a standard textbook example, so grab any stellar physics book at this point.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the formula.

Answer (score 0):

> How does gravity affect density?

The gravity of the body will work to increase its density. If we think of gravity as a force then to achieve equilibrium something needs to counteract the force of gravity, usually electromagnetic repulsion caused by neighboring electron shells. If we have more mass then we have more gravity, so atoms would be brought closer together until the electromagnetic repulsion equalizes with the gravity.
In general relativity the results are very similar.

> if I create 100 stars and planets all with the same density and random sizes, some of those stars are likely impossible to exist?

Yes. Two reasons:

First the stars density is different throughout its radius (denser towards the core), so if the density of the bodies you create is uniform then their size and density would definitely change until they achieve equilibrium (note that the major thing that counters gravity in stars is the outgoing matter and energy from the core instead of simple electromagnetic forces between relatively stationary atoms in a solid body). The case of the planets is with a similar result, but more complex, because planets have a more diverse composition in terms of materials.

Second if your radius gets large enough you would form a black hole. This radius for a non-rotating body is $$r = \sqrt{\frac{3c^2}{8\rho G}}
$$
Where $\rho$ is the density, $G$ is the gravitational constant, $c$ is the speed of light. More on that [in the Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius).

Comment: You mean "if your radius gets small enough" ? In fact, stable spherical objects are not even possible if their radii exceed the Schwarzschild radius by some small factor.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius#Parameters) Is a table of some bodies and their  Schwarzschild radius. It is obvious that things can be stable with radii far larger than their Schwarzschild radius. For instance the Schwarzschild radius for Earth is 0.00887 meters. I still mean "If the radius gets large enough" because we have a fixed _density_ for each body in the original question. So increasing the radius would actually bring us closer to forming a black hole, because the mass is proportional  to the third power of the radius.